# Export multiple html tables to Excel

Tags: html, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I've scavenged the inter web for answers and though I found some, they were mostly incomplete or not working.

What I'm trying to do is: I have a info page which displays information about a customer or server (or something else), this information is displayed in a table, sometimes multiple tables (I sometimes create my own table for some of the data and use Html.Grid(Model.list) to create tables for the rest of the data stored in lists, all on 1 page).

I found this website which is an awesome: http://www.excelmashup.com/ and does exactly what I want for **1** table, though I need this for multiple tables (they must all be in the same Excel file). I know I can create multiple files (1 for each table) but this is not the desired output.

So I kept on searching and I found a post on stackoverflow: [Export multiple HTML tables to Excel with JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480754/export-multiple-html-tables-to-excel-with-javascript-function)

This seemed promising so I tried using it but the code had some minor errors which I tried to fix:

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function (table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})()
```

The button I use to trigger it:

```
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('InformatieTable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
```

but alas to no avail (I did not know what to do with the `if (!table.nodeType) table = table` line so I just commented it since it seemed to do nothing special).

Now I get an error, or well not really an error but this is what it says when I try to run this code:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.ms-excel: "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,PGh0bWwgeG1sbnM6bz0idXJuOnNjaGVtYXMtbW…JzZXQ9VVRGLTgiLz48L2hlYWQ+PGJvZHk+PHRhYmxlPjwvdGFibGU+PC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4=".

And I get an Excel file as download in my browser but when I try to open it I get an error about the content and file extension not matching and if I would still like to open it. So if I click ok it opens a empty Excel sheet and that's it.

I am currently trying to fix that error, though i don't think it will make any difference to the content of the Excel file.

Is there anyone that can help me fix this? Or provide an other way of doing this?

I do prefer it to be run client side (so jQuery/java) instead of server side to minimize server load.

**EDIT**

I've found a better example of the jQuery (one that does work) on http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/755203/Export-HTML-table-to-Excel-With-CSS
This converts 1 table into an excel file which is obviously not good enough. But now I have the code to do this so I should be able to adapt it to loop trough all tables on the web page.

Also updated the code in this example to the correct version I'm using now.
I also still get the same error yet when I click on ok when trying to open the Excel file it does show me the content of the table, so I'm just ignoring that for now. anyone who has a solution for this please share.

Comment: For security reasons you cannot access the user's files with Javascript, so you have to do this on the server. However, MIME type problem is a big hint. If I were you, I would look at IIS MIME types first.

Comment: Ye I've been trying to find a solution for that, found some promising leads but nothing concrete yet.

Comment: Kindly read this: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-can-i-define-mime-types-on-my-windowsiis-based-site

Comment: yea i did that, did not help still getting the error.

Comment: What is really the goal? Get multiple HTML tables into one Excel sheet? Or get multiple HTML tables into multiple Excel sheets within one Excel workbook? If the latter, then have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301811/adding-worksheet-to-the-excel-file-using-javascript/26323012#26323012 And your "Error" is not really a error but a warning message. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825585/error-xls-is-in-a-different-format-than-specified-by-the-file-extension#comment42220946_26825585 for a discussion about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Axel Richter I got my answer, he reffered me to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301811/adding-worksheet-to-the-excel-file-using-javascript/26323012#26323012)

I have adapted the code a bit so it would Take all the tables on the web page so it now looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tablesToExcel = (function () {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
          + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
          + '<Styles>'
          + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
          + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
          + '</Styles>'
          + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
        , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
        , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function (wsnames, wbname, appname) {
            var ctx = "";
            var workbookXML = "";
            var worksheetsXML = "";
            var rowsXML = "";
            var tables = $('table');
            for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
                    rowsXML += '<Row>'
                    for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
                        var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
                        var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
                        var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
                        dataValue = (dataValue) ? dataValue : tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
                        var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
                        dataFormula = (dataFormula) ? dataFormula : (appname == 'Calc' && dataType == 'DateTime') ? dataValue : null;
                        ctx = {
                            attributeStyleID: (dataStyle == 'Currency' || dataStyle == 'Date') ? ' ss:StyleID="' + dataStyle + '"' : ''
                               , nameType: (dataType == 'Number' || dataType == 'DateTime' || dataType == 'Boolean' || dataType == 'Error') ? dataType : 'String'
                               , data: (dataFormula) ? '' : dataValue.replace('<br>', '')
                               , attributeFormula: (dataFormula) ? ' ss:Formula="' + dataFormula + '"' : ''
                        };
                        rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
                    }
                    rowsXML += '</Row>'
                }
                ctx = { rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i };
                worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
                rowsXML = "";
            }

            ctx = { created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML };
            workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);

            console.log(workbookXML);

            var link = document.createElement("A");
            link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
            link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
            link.target = '_blank';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    })();
</script>
```

so now when ever I want a page to have an option to be exported to excel i add a refference to that script and i add the following button to my page:

```
<button onclick="tablesToExcel(['ServerInformatie', 'Relaties'], 'VirtueleMachineInfo.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>
```

so the method:

```
tablesToExcel(WorksheetNames, fileName, 'Excel')
```

Where worksheetNames is an array which needs to contain as much names (or more) as there are tables on the page. You could ofcourse chose to create the worksheet names in a different way.
And where fileName is ofcourse the name of the file you'll be downloading.

Not having it all in 1 worksheet is a shame but at least this will do for now.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code that I used to put multiple HTML tables in the same Excel sheet:

```js
import TableExport from 'tableexport';

const tbOptions = {
  formats: ["xlsx"],    // (String[]), filetype(s) for the export, (default: ['xlsx', 'csv', 'txt'])
  bootstrap: true,                   // (Boolean), style buttons using bootstrap, (default: true)
  exportButtons: false,                // (Boolean), automatically generate the built-in export buttons for each of the specified formats (default: true)
  position: "bottom",                 // (top, bottom), position of the caption element relative to table, (default: 'bottom')
}

DowlandExcel = (key) => {
  const table = TableExport(document.getElementById(key), tbOptions);
  var exportData = table.getExportData();
  var xlsxData = exportData[key].xlsx;
  console.log(xlsxData); // Replace with the kind of file you want from the exportData
  table.export2file(xlsxData.data, xlsxData.mimeType, xlsxData.filename, xlsxData.fileExtension, xlsxData.merges, xlsxData.RTL, xlsxData.sheetname)
}

DowlandExcelMultiTable = (keys) => {

  const tables = []
  const xlsxDatas = []
  keys.forEach(key => {
    const selector = document.getElementById(key);
    if (selector) {
      const table = TableExport(selector, tbOptions);
      tables.push(table);
      xlsxDatas.push(table.getExportData()[key].xlsx)
    }
  });

  const mergeXlsxData = {
    RTL: false,
    data: [],
    fileExtension: ".xlsx",
    filename: 'rapor',
    merges: [],
    mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    sheetname: "Rapor"
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < xlsxDatas.length; i++) {
    const xlsxData = xlsxDatas[i];
    mergeXlsxData.data.push(...xlsxData.data)

    xlsxData.merges = xlsxData.merges.map(merge => {
      const diff = mergeXlsxData.data.length - xlsxData.data.length;

      merge.e.r += diff;
      merge.s.r += diff;

      return merge
    });
    mergeXlsxData.merges.push(...xlsxData.merges)
    mergeXlsxData.data.push([null]);
  }
  console.log(mergeXlsxData);
  tables[0].export2file(mergeXlsxData.data, mergeXlsxData.mimeType, mergeXlsxData.filename, mergeXlsxData.fileExtension, mergeXlsxData.merges, mergeXlsxData.RTL, mergeXlsxData.sheetname)
}
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is strictly an English Q&A only. Posts containing anything else risk being deleted.

Comment: @costaparas I'm sorry it's my fault.